# Who should I list as my manager on my resume?

Tags: resume

When I was hired for my current internship position, I was told that I would be reporting to person X - his name was listed on my offer letter, and he is who I corresponded with before my assignment started.

However, during my work I've been reporting to someone else instead, person Y.

When listing this job on my resume, should I list person X or person Y?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't list your managers on your resume, for any position.

Future employers will care about the work you did, and when and where you did it, not who you reported to.

For references (which you typically provide on request, at a later stage, not on your resume), use the one you actually reported to and worked with (if they'd provide a good reference, that is). Although references are typically for previous rather than current employment, since you generally don't want your current employer to know you're looking for another job, and they may not feel comfortable giving a reference. But it might be okay for roles with a fixed end date, where you're looking for jobs starting after that date.

Comment: Although you should probably not provide your *current* manager as a reference in most cases, as it's usually none of their business that you're looking for another job. I suppose it might be okay if you're an intern and they're expecting you to be looking, but I would still avoid it if there's a chance they might be interested in offering you a permanent position.

Comment: I totally agree, but will add that anyone asking me for references has asked for them "from previous positions".